# How to define a data structure using a variable for the name?

Tags: python

I am somewhat new to Python - after searching I cannot find an answer to this 'simple' question.

I am defining several custom data structures, and need each one to be named after the value contained in a variable. I am sure the answer is very simple - code shows an example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
 class aDataStructure:
     def __init__(self, value):
          self.value=value

 String1 = "name"

 # How to define this data structure with the String contained in 'String1'?
 ??? = aDataStructure ('a value')

 print name.value
```

Comment: Why do you want to name a data structure by the *value*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do variable variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python), if you need to use variable variables, a good implementation is to use a dictionary, which maps the variable tied to the name onto the data structure you're creating:

```
>>> string1 = "name"
>>> dict = {string1 : aDataStructure('a value')}
>>> dict["name"]
<__main__.aDataStructure instance at 0x10ce1db48>
```